# How to select multi row values without querying database using 1 line of SQL?

Tags: sql, select, syntax

I need to write a SELECT query in one line only that could potentially return *n* number of rows.

eg

`select 1 as 'primary', 'peter@email.com' as 'email'`

Will return 1 row with column primary=1 and column email peter@email.com

My parser does not read beyond the first SELECT - so i need to write all this data using 1 select. I have searched a bit but cant really find a proper answer.

eg.

`select (1 as 'primary', 'peter@email.com' as 'email'),(2 as 'primary', 'dave@email.com' as 'email')`

does not work..

Comment: What database? does it have to begin with a SELECT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
select 1 as 'primary', 'peter@email.com' as 'email' union select 2, 'dave@email.com'
```